# How to make an item fall down with css3 animation

Tags: css

I am working on an exercise about CSS 3 animation. I am stuck on how to keep the item falling down the page at full speed without requiring the user to follow it down with the mouse without resorting to javascript. So just when you hover the mouse over the box the box will fall down.

Here is my code:

```
<p class="exp9"><strong>box</strong></p>

strong {
    margin-top: 20em;
}

p:hover strong {
    display: block;
}

p:hover strong:hover {
    margin-top: 20em;
}
```

My code just make the text inside the box drop down. Any idea? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
/*newly added items start faded out and translated 400px upwards on the y-axis*/
li.new-item {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: new-item-animation .3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes new-item-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-400px);
}

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform : translateY(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you can do:

```
<div class="box">
    <p class="innerbox">
        Hover
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.innerbox
{
    Width:150px;
    height:20px;
    background-color: lightBlue;
    Text-align: center;
    Padding:10px 0px;
}

.box
{
    Display:inline-block;
    Transition: 0.3s 0s All linear;
}

.box:hover
{
    Padding-top:20em;
}
```

In the context of your HTML:

```
strong 
{
    Text-align: center; /* this makes it more aesthetic */
    Padding:10px 20px; /* this makes the text more easy to hover over */

}

p
{
    Display: inline-block; /* this is so the box doesn't stretch the width of the page */
    Transition: 0.3s 0s all linear;
}

p:hover
{
    padding-top: 20em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the result you want.

```css
p{
  width: max-content; /*add this if you don't want the paragraph to take the whole width*/
}
p strong{
  display: block;
}
p:hover strong{
  animation: fall .1s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes fall{
  0%{
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(20em);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="exp9"><strong>box</strong></p>
```